# Where is the best place to report a common type of IA defect (might not be under SE)?

Tags: support, wordpress.org, user-interface

I helped my father with something he was stuck on, and successfully contributed to http://hume.haywards.family. Incidentally, my father is a computer scientist, probably knows PHP like the back of his hand, but this was his first Wordpress site.

What he specifically asked my help for was removing a coffeeshop advertisement-style image on the *homepage* that twentyseventeen had tucked in a corner. For this and one or two other issues, he asked my help for things that are simple enough (and I doubt he will be needing much more help), but there was an information architecture that probably has its own technical term: a program or system of some description is built according to an information architecture that more or less makes sense, and then later something is added that does not have its own proper space, and what happens is that the new item is added, but there is no logical place for it in the IA, so it gets tucked somewhere that you pretty much have to know for finding it. I've had this on a church website too, where there were routine pages including homepage, contact information, clergy, schedule of services, "what we believe", and then, tucked in some odd spot, "How to build an analoy icon stand" [a HOWTO on constructing something that some Orthodox parishes would like]. On that one, my work was not only technology adaptations; I worked on rearchitecting the site so that it had room for informational pages such as a HOWTO, intended to gracefully accommodate not only that specific page but other informational or HOWTO postings that people might like to add down the road.

Twentyseventeen has an information architecture defect that makes it not obvious where one would navigate to perform an obvious setup task: where to go to get replace or eliminate the coffeeshop imagery and content.

So, a couple of questions:

First, is there anything to be done to report an IA defect? Or is this sort of a "best compromise we can manage" result where there's only so much the theme authors can do to make editing homepage content something easily found?

Second, if not, what is the proper forum to report IA defect like this? Ordinarily on meta.xyz.stackexchange.com one asks, "Which stack should I use to post my slightly different question?" Here I'm expecting most likely to get instructions to file a report about XYZ on a Wordpress-owned-site.

Comment: You might be better off, trying to convince someone on Slack. Maybe you can [get a Make post](https://make.wordpress.org/design/) as result of your search. Refactoring the theme, presenting your case in a GitHub repo might be a route to go down as well.

Answer (score 3):

Twenty Seventeen is considered to be part of WordPress core.

While the theme itself has been developed on GitHub, the proper channel for reporting issues in it is same as WordPress core — https://core.trac.wordpress.org/